# PHPUnit 4.8 Mock mysql database interface

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, phpunit

Good afternoon,

I have a bunch of legacy code that uses the old `mysql` library (`mysql_query($sql)` for example) and am trying to test it with PHPUnit (4.8 is the latest that will run on the server for various reasons).

Does anyone know how to mock this database connection so that it can return predetermined results when predetermined queries are run? I have tried using getConnection() (as per the docs here: http://devdocs.io/phpunit~4/database) to no avail.

For example I have this class:

```
class Raffle {
    ...
    public static function loadAll($filter=""){
        //$filter = mysql_real_escape_string($filter); // protect against SQL injection
        $raffles = []; // the array to return

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM raffles $filter;"; // include the user filter in the query
        $query = mysql_query($sql);

        //echo mysql_error();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $raffles[] = Raffle::loadFromRow($row); // generate the raffe instance and add it to the array
        }
        return $raffles; // return the array
    }
    ...
}
```

(The `mysql_connect()` call is done in a file called `db.php` which is loaded on every page that it is needed and not in the class file itself.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us some code, like how is created the connection, is it passed by DI? instanciated directly in the class that use it? it could help us.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by DI, but basically there is a file that calls `mysql_connect()` with the credentials which is then imported in every public page. So when the class is loaded on the page the mysql connection is already opened. I almost managed to work around it with an interesting Mocking method. If It works I'll post it as an answer tommorow :-)!. Thanks!

Comment: by DI i talk about Dependency Injection, please show your code, its more efficient than words to explain a problem, and found the solution. Show us the function/method you want to test and how/where the connection is created. Ok best luck for your try.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code anyway :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else stuck in this situation I found that building a mock for PDO that contains a fallback to the functional api allowed me to migrate the code to a Testable OO based model while still using the old `mysql` library under the hood.

For example:

```
// the basic interfaces (function names taken from PDO
interface DBConnAdapter {
    public function query($sql);
}
// since PDO splits connections and statements the adapter should do the same
interface DBQueryAdapter {
    public function num_rows();
    public function fetch_assoc();
}
...
class DBAdapter implements DBConnAdapter {

    public function query($sql){
        $query = mysql_query($sql); // run the query using the legacy api
        return $query ? new QueryAdapter($query) : false; // return a new query adapter or false.
    }

}
...
// an example of a basic mock object to test sql queries being sent to the server (inspired by mockjax :-) ) 
class DBMock implements DBConnAdapter {

    public $queries = []; // array of queries already executed
    public $results = []; // array of precomputed results. (key is SQL and value is the returned result (nested array))

    public function query($sql) {
        if($this->results[$sql]){
            $query = new DBQueryMock($sql, $this->results[$sql]); // a mock of PDOStatement that takes the sql it ran and the results to return
            $queries[] = $query; // add the query to the array
            return $query; // return the query
        }
        return false; // we do not know the statement so lets pretend it failed
    }
    // add a result to the list
    public function add_single_result($sql, $result){
        // check if the index was set, if not make an array there
        if(!isset($this->results[$sql])) $this->results[$sql] = [];
        // add the result to the end of the array
        $this->results[$sql][] = $result; 
        // return its index
        return count($this->results[$sql]) - 1;
    }
}
```

Admittedly this is not an ideal solution as it requires modifying the code to support the adapter objects and removes some functionality (such as `mysql_real_escape_string`), but it worked....

If you have a better solution please share :-) Thanks!